# how to use floating search view with a list view loaded by json?

Tags: android, json, search, view, floating

I load a list view using json ,this is work fine.Now i want to add a floating search view to this list .I dont know how use it correcte and how to implement my own searchable function.can you some one help me.
this is my code  in main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    EditText textView;
    Spinner s;
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;
FloatingSearchView mSearchView;
    // URL to get contacts JSON
//    private static String url ="http://10.3.216.241/WorkServIndus.nsf/ListeClient.xsp/ListeClient";
    private static String url ="http://myadress/WorkServIndus.nsf/ListeClient.xsp/ListeClient";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //  s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
       new GetContacts().execute();
    }



    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);


                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                            //  return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                            String test=c.getString("ServiFournisseur");
                            String name = c.getString("universalID");
                            final  String localite=c.getString("Localite");

    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

    contact.put("universalID", name);
    contact.put("ServiFournisseur", test);
    // contact.put("Localite", localite);
    //  contact.put("ServiFournisseur", lt_name);
    // contact.put("location", location);

    // adding contact to contact list
    contactList.add(contact);






                           // String lt_name = c.getString("ServiFournisseur");
                            // String location = c.getString("location");
                            //    return new JSONObject(jsonStr.substring(jsonStr.indexOf("{"), jsonObj.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
                            // tmp hash map for single contact

                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, contactList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"universalID","ServiFournisseur"
                }, new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.email
                       });
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

    }
```

this is my class for connection :

```
public class HttpHandler
{
    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

this is the main layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tn.servi.mytest.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
            android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="true"
            app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchHint="Search..."
            app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="false"
            app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250" />

        <!-- List View -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="213dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="56dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mSearchView.setOnQueryChangeListener(new FloatingSearchView.OnQueryChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onSearchTextChanged(String oldQuery, final String newQuery) {

                  //get suggestions based on newQuery

                  //pass them on to the search view
                  mSearchView.swapSuggestions(newSuggestions);
              }
          });
```

Comment: hi ,thank you for the response but what is swap suggestion ?

Comment: pass responce array as param in it.

Comment: i enter your code in oncreate() but the program reports an error at the level new suggestions(Error:(71, 45) error: cannot find symbol variable newSuggestions)

Comment: you mean jsonarray?

Comment: Ok my code signal  a error when I put cantacts(my json array like mention in the code)

Comment: Error:(145, 66) error: incompatible types: JSONArray cannot be converted to List<? extends SearchSuggestion>

Comment: please check my code an tell me where i use  your code in the created function or in background functiontion?

Comment: get repsonce in Arraylist then pass to it. if not work check Link mention here:
https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/arlib/floatingsearchviewdemo/fragment/SlidingSearchResultsExampleFragment.java